# Server 2008 print server with existing printers

Tags: print-server, shared-printers

I recently started new job and one of my tasks is to look into all systems and ensure they are properly configured and running at optimal settings.

One of the issues I run into is the print server. Apparently my predecessor has set up the print server by simply installing networked printers onto the Server 2008R2 VM and sharing them over network. The actual role of 'Print server' has not been enabled.

So my first task would be to enable the appropriate role on the server.
My question is what will happen with the printers already configured in the system. Will they be seamlessly 'acquired' by the new role or can I expect some delay or downtime longer than 15min?

I never came across a situation like this before, and there is nothing on the net hinting on possible problems.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the Print Management Role will have no effect on the currently installed shared printers, so you can do this without any risk to your current setup.

The Print Management snapin will show all installed printers and allow you to manage them as necessary.

Bear in mind Print Management is purely a snap in to aid management of shared printers on the network. In an environment with few printers or print servers, it's hardly worth the time it takes to install. Most of my clients only have one print server and three or four shared printers, so I generally share and add to group policy manually rather than using Print Management. With more complex sites, it can be useful to have a centralised management location.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it's a site with 5 different buildings and over 50 printer so the print role will make the management much easier.

Comment: Yes - definitely would recommend the print role for that environment. It could be that the previous sysadmin may have had the role installed somewhere that you haven't discovered yet! Alternatively, he may have been old school and wasn't even aware of its existence - I was brought up on NT, and it was a while before I discovered the print role in later versions!